# How do I reduce this ketone to two double bonds on the carbo chain?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

What reactants should I use to get from 1,5-diphenylpentan-3-one to ((1E,3E)-penta-1,3-diene-1,5-diyl)dibenzene (picture for reference)? Either in 1 step or in multiple steps. I have tried $\ce{NaBH4}$ in acid, then $\ce{POCl3}$ in pyridine, but that only gives one double bond. Is there a way to get both double bonds ?

[image: Reaction of 1,5-diphenylpentan-3-one to ((1E,3E)-penta-1,3-diene-1,5-diyl)dibenzene, no reactants specified.]

Answer (score 6):

This can be done (on paper) by alpha-selenation of the starting ketone followed by selenoxide elimination to form the alkene ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenoxide_elimination)).

The product from this can be reduced by [Luche reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luche_reduction) ($\ce{NaBH4/CeCl3}$) to the allylic alcohol.

Finally this can undergo acid catalysed dehydration (PTSA/toluene Dean-Stark reflux) to give the diene.